# How to make Helm work on local single instance Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have following local setup of Kubernetes (via conjure up) just for testing purposes.

````
```
$ microk8s.kubectl get all

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.152.183.1   <none>        443/TCP   71m
```
````

I can access following URL:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps

This is working fine as below:

[image]

Helm/tiller is also installed:

````
```
$ microk8s.kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system 

NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
tiller-deploy-85686555b8-kbkhv   1/1     Running   0          105s
```
````

My problem starts once I run `helm ls` command.
I am getting following error:

> Error: Get
>   https://10.152.183.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?labelSelector=OWNER%!D(MISSING)TILLER:
>   dial tcp 10.152.183.1:443: i/o timeout

There are 2 problems here:

1- Once I hit following URL from Firefox, it gives me certificate error:

https://10.152.183.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?labelSelector=OWNER%!D(MISSING)TILLER:

If I add exception and continue, then it asks me master username/password:

[image]

2- When I run `microk8s.kubectl config view` this gives following output with no password:

````
```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: http://127.0.0.1:8080
  name: microk8s-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: microk8s-cluster
    user: admin
  name: microk8s
current-context: microk8s
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admin
  user:
    username: admin
```
````

So my questions are:

1- Where can I find that master password (I have not set any on setup)?
2- How can I make that SSL cert run with trust? So, once I do `helm ls`, it should just work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem of ubuntu firewall, fixed as below.

https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/67

> So the fix was:
>
> `sudo ufw allow in on cbr0 && sudo ufw allow out on cbr0`